# jQuery slideToggle menu Jitter/Jump

Tags: jquery, nav

Hi all I am struggling with my responsive nav

I have made the nav and jQuery for this. It works however the animation for the slideToggle is awful, please see attached link and if anyone has any working solutions I look forward to trying your responses.

When I click on the burger icon, the nav shows as it should, however if you click it, you will notice that the animation of the slideToggle jitters and jumps at the end of the animation

I’ll add in code blocks in the morning maybe that’ll help

Regards

Jon

http://www.grid.jonfullerwebdesign.co.uk/

Comment: Hi Jon, Actually what do you want? I can't understand your question.

Comment: question edited

Comment: I can see in your code, when calling the `.slidetoggle()` method, you're passing through `1e3` as a parameter? Try removing it or passing through `200` or `100`.

Comment: When I wrote it I passed through 1000 - just checked my code before upload is 1000

Comment: I have just edited it to be 100, the jumping is still happening?

Comment: Looks like some CSS is causing the jump, though I can't see exactly what at the minute

Comment: I think it nav tag padding issue. Remove padding and apply slideToggle for just testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I had a css something similar to as follows

```
*{
transition: all 0.3s ease;
```

}

This was causing conflict with the jquery I believe